# JasperReport start page numbering after page break

Tags: jasper-reports, page-break, page-numbering

How to start new (from 1) page numbering after page break?
I have 5 pages well page numbered. And after that 5 pages I want to insert page break and after that page break I want to add 5 more pages with page number start from 1.

```
page1(#1)
page2(#2)
page3(#3)
page4(#4)
page5(#5)
pagebreak
page6(#1)
page7(#2)
page8(#3)
page9(#4)
page10(#5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a jasper report variable, which will reset after the page break (for whichever group).